# Multi Monitor Selecting

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I want to use multi monitors. Like when application started , I will see all monitors and click one of them ,then application will start the monitor that I selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`EnumDisplayDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa) to enumerate display adapters and monitors. Call [`ChangeDisplaySettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa) to move and/or turn monitors on/off.

Call `MonitorFromPoint` and `GetMonitorInfo` to find the work area for application windows.